# How can I reset my windows password using Google Compute Engine api

Tags: google-compute-engine

I've written a c# program to create VMs in the google compute engine hypervisor, using the .net api to create the VMs.
Using the console I see there is a way to reset the windows password, however I can't find the option in the .net api.  Can this be done via the api?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I used the MetaData to set the gce-initial-windows-user and gce-initial-windows-password